# Silverlight detect running sllauncher.exe

Tags: c#, silverlight

We're running a Silverlight out of browser app on a Windows XP Box. Occasionally, this app hangs and has to be closed. When we attempt to restart the app after this situation, the app starts in a strange state. We look in the TaskManager and see multiple instances of sllauncher.exe running. The solution is to terminate the sllauncher.exe instances and start the app again (of course, the real solution is to deal with the problem that caused the app to hang in the first place...).

What I would like to do, is upon start up of our silverlight app, detect if multiple instances of sllauncher.exe are running and display a message to the user indicating what corrective action should be taken. Can my out of browser silverlight app gain access to a list of running processes?

Comment: Also, if you consider going down my route, drop me a mail and I send you some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we did it...

We created a message receiver. If we are unable to listen using the same key, then we assume another instance is running. Then we ask the user if he/she wants to kill the current instance or the one that's already running. In the received message event handler, we kill the window if a message comes in. Not the most elegant solution, but it worked. The most important thing was to draw attention to the fact that more than one instance was running.

```
try
{
    LocalMessageReceiver receiver = new LocalMessageReceiver("There can be only one");
    receiver.Listen();
    receiver.MessageReceived += receiver_MessageReceived;
}
catch (ListenFailedException)
{
    log.Info("Another instance is running.");
    // Display message, take corrective action etc.
    interactionService.ShowMessage(Strings.OneInstanceAllowed,
                                           Strings.ApplicationName, DialogButton.OKCancel, DialogImage.Question,
                                           OnCloseClientResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very likely, and you can also kill them with TerminateProcess in a P/Invoke - as long as you have elevated permissions.

I'm developing a signage solution (a long-running, remote-controlled video player) and recently I had a very similar problem. Since my crashes are very rare and I don't get any logging, I also settled to go down the "just restart it" way to alleviate the problem.

However, I do it slightly different in that I run a native (WPF) satellite application from silverlight that comes embedded in the xap. Since it's started by the silverlight player, it can get the process id as a parameter on startup. It then has a long chat with the silverlight player (over http, the port is also given on startup) and in case the silverlight partner suddenly silences, it restarts it.

The restart is done by first trying to close the main window and if that doesn't work after a short waiting period, it's killed.

Since the satellite is .NET, I didn't need any P/Invoke for that logic.

If you want to do it purely in Silverlight, have a look at [the interop wiki](http://www.pinvoke.net/).

For a list of processes GetConsoleProcessList in kernel32.dll sounds promising. The code snippets work in WPF and Silverlight alike.